# Update Host Header in IIS with Powershell

Tags: powershell, iis-7.5

**Goal**: Update an existing host header for an IIS7.5 site with powershell

**Problem**: `Set-WebBinding` requires the name of the site which I don't have. I do have the HostHeader though.

**Scenario**: I have multiple sites in IIS. Some of them have a host header with a particular string that I want to change.

```
Site1 - site1.stuff.domain.net
Site2 - site2.stuff.domain.net
Site3 - site3.domain.net
```

I want to change all sites that have `.stuff` in their headers.

I'm using `Get-WebBinding` to get a list of all sites and their bindings. I then loop through them and check if `bindingInformation` contains `.stuff`. I modify the string how I please and then go to update the header with

```
Set-WebBinding -HostHeader $originalHeader -SetProperty HostHeader -Value $newHeader
```

Apparently though, you have to have the site's name in order to use `Set-WebBinding`, unlike `Get-WebBinding` which allows you to get a binding based on the HostHeader (`Get-WebBinding -HostHeader $someValue`). Is there a way to use `Set-WebBinding` without specifing the `Name` of a site? Is there a way I can get the site's name from `Get-WebBinding`? Is there an alternative to `Set-WebBinding`? Or is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
Get-WebBinding -HostHeader *.stuff.* | Foreach-Object{
    #$NewHeader = $_.bindingInformation -replace '\.stuff\.','.staff.'
    Set-WebConfigurationProperty -Filter $_.ItemXPath -PSPath IIS:\ -Name Bindings -Value @{protocol='http';bindingInformation=$NewHeader}
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work where there are multiple bindings per site. In this case $_.ItemXPath property value is the same, so effectively only last binding survives.

Answer (score 1):

Modified Shay's answer to support multiple bindings.

```
Get-WebBinding -HostHeader *.stuff.* | Foreach-Object{
    #$NewHeader = $_.bindingInformation -replace '\.stuff\.','.staff.'
    Set-WebConfigurationProperty -Filter ($_.ItemXPath + "/bindings/binding[@protocol='http' and @bindingInformation='" + $_.bindingInformation + "']") -PSPath IIS:\ -Name bindingInformation -Value $NewHeader
}
```