# libraries and help for changing iis setting through .net windows tool. (Not asp.net)

Tags: .net, iis

I want to make .net window standalone tool. which will be run on iis server web.
I need to change some website setting like http headers.for example i want to remove custom http headers from website property throught this this .net windows tool.

please help me to find out the class that will be needed for this code in .net. 
how can i change the http headers and other property settings for website hosted on iis thruogh .net code. i want c# code or library? (this is not asp application)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Powershell to modify iis settings or any other stuff. Though I have not written any app myself to do what you want to do.

But the refrences below might help.

How to use Powershell from C# - [Link](http://csharpening.net/?p=951)

Someone asked a question on Stackoverflow about mofiying the host header in IIS using Powershell. This might give you some guidance. [Stack Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233366/update-host-header-in-iis-with-powershell)

So using powershell from C# might be your answer.