# powershell script to apply host header name to an existing binding of a site in IIS

Tags: powershell, iis

I want to apply host header name to an existing binding of a site in IIS.
So far i got this command but it creates a new binding but i want to apply the hostheader to the existing one.
Below is the command:

```
new-webbinding -hostheader hostheadername -name sitename -protocol http
```

Is there any command to do this?

any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Might be a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233366/update-host-header-in-iis-with-powershell

Answer (score 1):

You can easily construct this yourself using [`Set-WebBinding`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790557.aspx).

Example:

```
Import-Module WebAdministration;
Set-WebBinding -Name "www.example.com" -HostHeader "original.example.com" -PropertyName "HostHeader" -Value "new.example.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried using the set command

```
set -webbinding -hostheader hostheadername -name sitename
```